# Constant error when trying to create SSRS reports after installing SSDT for visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, installation, sql-server-data-tools

I tried everything that came to my mind and everything I've read from Google that looked like a potential solution.

**Summery of the problem**

After installing Visual Studio 2015 on a virtual machine (windows 7) I tested creation of an MVC project. Went fine. Then i installed SSDT to be able to make SSRS reports on this virtual machine, installation also went well. But now when I try to create an SSRS repports, I get this error :

> Unspecified error (HRESULT exception : 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

E_FAIL ! How ironic and accurate.

I then tried on another virtual machine... same result.

---

**Detailed steps of installation**

---

**1. Virtual Machine**

As mentioned above, virtual machines are Windows 7, I can't think of anything very special that would make these machine different than a windows 7. One thing I can say though is that a COMPLETE installation worked on a physical machine once... but never on a virtual machine so far.

Here's some specs but I would say it's not worth looking at :

[image]

**2. Visual Studio 2015**

VS is installed from an ISO file, mounted by Virtual CloneDrive, type of installation is default and nothing surprising happens here. Even creating projects is possible and I did create MVC projects fine.

Specs :

[image]

**3. SSDT**

The add-up I used is downloadable from this link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Without it, you can't make SSRS repport in Visual Studio.

Note that you have to take SSDT for Visual Studio 2015, at the right of the screen, not the link on the left.

On my first virtual machine, I downloaded from the link and installation went well. I chose to check all the check-boxes options and install everything.

On my second virtual machine, I chose to download it as an ISO, and install it the same way I installed VS 2015 (still checking all the check-boxes).

In both case, once everything is done, I can't create a new SSRS project. Every time I try i get this error and an empty project :

[image]

**4. Panicking and trying all kind of things to solve the problem**

After googling this out, I tried to repair Visual Studio. Using the VS setup, there is the Repair option, waited very long for the repair to be done but still, it doesn't change anything.

I tried to install everything on another virtual machine, telling myself the previous one was broken, but nope. After all I tested, the only time it worked was one year ago when I installed on my physical machine. Since then it has been a pile of fails.

Comment: Hi Antonie, please go to Tools>Extensions and Updates>Updates>Product updates and download the VS 2015 update 3 to upgrade, I tried to install the VS 2015 enterprise with update 3 on the Win 7 SP1 Virtual machine, then download the SSDT that you shared, go to File-New-Project-Installed-Business Intelligence-Reporting Services to create a new project, it works fine. Meanwhile, you can have a try with 1. run vs as admin 2. repair IIS Express 3. Choose a different location store folder during the creation of the project, like C:\Project2015

Comment: Thanks for your attention @SaraLiu-MSFT, it's really appreciated. I tried everything mentioned in your 3 points. But what is update 3 exactly ? What do you mean ? There in update panel i updated everything even though it's not related... didn't see any "update 3"

Comment: OK, i found Update 3 on my physical machine... my physical doesn't even have it and SSDT works. All the other way around for my virtual machine...

Comment: Please try to download VS 2015 update 3: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/, sign in with your Microsoft account and join the VS dev essential(free). If this issue persists, completely uninstall the VS 2015: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/ and remove SSDT, re-download the VS professional 2015 with update 3 from the above link, make sure windows update is up-to-date, click ‘Custom’ and check the option Windows and Web Development>Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools to install then re-install SSDT.